# fill generic list<> of a class file with data by specific variables

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, fill

The question is rather about serialized generic list<>

I have used a tool xsd2code for generating a serialized class file from xml schema to generate xml file on given data.

The class file contains all the xml data fields variables into classes as bellow-

public partial class Awmds
    {
        private List bol_segmentField;

```
    public Awmds()
    {
        this.bol_segmentField = new List<AwmdsBol_segment>();
    }
    public List<AwmdsBol_segment> Bol_segment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bol_segmentField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bol_segmentField = value;
        }
    }
}
public partial class AwmdsBol_segment
{
    private AwmdsBol_segmentBol_id bol_idField;

    private sbyte consolidated_CargoField;

    private AwmdsBol_segmentLoad_unload_place load_unload_placeField;

    private AwmdsBol_segmentTraders_segment traders_segmentField;

    private List<AwmdsBol_segmentCtn_segment> ctn_segmentField;

    private AwmdsBol_segmentGoods_segment goods_segmentField;

    private string value_segmentField;

    public AwmdsBol_segment()
    {
        this.goods_segmentField = new AwmdsBol_segmentGoods_segment();
        this.ctn_segmentField = new List<AwmdsBol_segmentCtn_segment>();
        this.traders_segmentField = new AwmdsBol_segmentTraders_segment();
        this.load_unload_placeField = new AwmdsBol_segmentLoad_unload_place();
        this.bol_idField = new AwmdsBol_segmentBol_id();
    }


    public AwmdsBol_segmentBol_id Bol_id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bol_idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bol_idField = value;
        }
    }

    public sbyte Consolidated_Cargo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.consolidated_CargoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.consolidated_CargoField = value;
        }
    }
     .... and so on for other fields ....

}


public partial class AwmdsBol_segmentBol_id
{

    private string bol_referenceField;

    private sbyte line_numberField;

    private sbyte bol_natureField;

    private string bol_type_codeField;

    public string Bol_reference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bol_referenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bol_referenceField = value;
        }
    }

    public sbyte Line_number
    {
        get
        {
            return this.line_numberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.line_numberField = value;
        }
    }

    public sbyte Bol_nature
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bol_natureField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bol_natureField = value;
        }
    }

    public string Bol_type_code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bol_type_codeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bol_type_codeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

.... and so on for other classes ....

I have all the data to fill the generic list: List bol_segmentField

My problem is I dont know how to insert the data to the members of List bol_segmentField based on the class file.

Someone please help me to fillup the generic list by the class variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but would this work:

```
var awds = new Awmds();
var segment = new AwmdsBol_segment();
// here fill in the segment
awds.Bol_segment.Add(segment);
```

Comment: thanks. what I tried is-
    Awmds xmlRoot = new Awmds();
    xmlRoot.Bol_segment = create_Bol_List();

    private List<AwmdsBol_segment> create_Bol_List()
        { 

    ... I have all my data into datatable here, need to assign all valures to the list<AwmdsBol_segment>. But I cant :(


return bolData;
    }

Comment: Martin, how can I fill the var segment matching with the class file serialized structure?